# Woocommerce Shop show categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress so please still help with me if I get the language wrong.

Using woocommerce to display a shop with variable products, I would like the shop link landing page to display the shop categories with the featured image of that category.

My current shop page displays all products, with a pagination to other product pages and I cannot find the template for all products.

When I go to shop page in wp-admin and click on the edit page it is empty, so am not sure how they are getting there in the frst place and I have looked at the HTML not just the visual editor.

Many Thanks
Asa.

Answer (score 16):

It's easy, just go to `'WooCommerce -> Settings'` link from side bar admin menu & select `'Catalog'` tab & then tick 2 check boxes `"Show subcategories on the shop page"` & `"When showing subcategories, hide product" -> click 'Save Changes'` button at bottom. That's it! You are Done!

Now visit 'Shop' page you'll be able to see categories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

This is now in `Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display`, 'Shop Page Display' drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

In current version 3.4.5 there is no display option under `Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display`. It has been moved to customizer under `Woocommerce->Product Catalog`