# How to show WooCommerce Categories on 'shop' page instead of products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214845/woocommerce-shop-show-categories). That does not work.

---

### Setup

I am running:

- WordPress 5.4.1
- WooCommerce 4.1.1

I have a custom theme that overrides some of the WooCommerce templates by placing my own templates in: **themes/my_theme/woocommerce/template-name.php**

I have established that the shop page (homepage) uses the template **archive-product.php**. I have copied the this from **plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php** into my theme and made some minor HTML changes which work perfectly. There are no functional changes in my theme's copy, just some HTML.

### The problem

I want the homepage to only show the store categories, as thumbnails. There is an option to set the shop page to show categories instead of products:

**Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Catalogue**

Shop page display has been set to **Show Categories**

[image]

However the shop homepage seems to ignore this setting entirely, and it still shows the products. It seems surprising that WooCommerce's *own template* does not honour this setting!

How do I find this setting in the template and then show the categories (as thumbnails) on the shop homepage?

Is there an equivalent to `woocommerce_product_loop()` for looping categories?

---

*As a side note, the Storefront theme does honour the setting but Storefront does not have the template **archive-product.php**. Storefront seems to be highly abstracted and after much debugging of it / trying to take it apart I have so far not worked out which template file it is using for the shop page.*

*My theme is already in production and I just want to make an update so that the homepage shows the categories instead of going directly into the products list.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workable solution. The WooCommerce default templates don't support the setting to show categories on the Shop page.

However using a shortcode with `do_shortcode()`, and a condition this can be achieved as follows:

```
if (is_shop()) {

  echo do_shortcode('[product_categories hide_empty="0"]');

} else {

  woocommerce_product_loop_start();

  if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();

      /**
      * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
      */
      do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

      wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }

  }

  woocommerce_product_loop_end();
}
```

Still:

- I would like to know how to pick up the 'show categories' customisation setting shown in the question, so my theme responds to that.
- Is there a better way than using `do_shortcode()`, this feels like a bit of a hack